# Is there a name / descriptor for "elevated backgrounds"?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to find a good naming structure to name commonly "elevated" elements in box-like components. What I mean by this is not buttons or similar things, but rows with different background colors, often used in elements like table-headers/footers, cards, WYSIWYG editors and similar "header" elements. In fact, while asking this question, StackExchange already gives me 2 examples for these "elevated" elements:

[image]

Now, the obvious term may be "header", but I'm looking for a more generalized word since this can often apply for footers and elements that aren't considered headers. "Elevation" may be a good term for it, but perhaps there is something a bit more neutral (since the styling doesn't necessarily elevate these elements - as seen with StackExchange's text editor).

My goal is just to have some structure when it comes to wording and styling. Similar terms are "container", "card", "nav", "header", "body", "footer", "hero", etc. I'm missing a good descriptor to refer to these common "elevated" elements/rows.

Are there any best practices or common terms for naming these things?

Comment: These sections are not elevated and are just cards' headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some graphics applications like Illustrator or Photoshop, the header or footer with tool options are called just *bar*: tool options bar.

The footer at the example image would be the *tools bar* while the header, *title bar*.

Comment: Toolbar is correct for, well, a bar with tools; a title bar is something else https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_decoration#Title_bar

Comment: @Luciano you're right, but I think that really makes "bar" a good word to generally describe these "special rows".